# How can I get Knockout JS to data-bind on keypress instead of lost-focus?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This example of [knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/) works so when you edit a field and press TAB, the viewmodel data  and hence the text below the fields is updated.

**How can I change this code so that the viewmodel data is updated every keypress?**

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>knockout js</title>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-1.1.1.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload= function() {

            var viewModel = {
                firstName : ko.observable("Jim"),
                lastName : ko.observable("Smith")
            };
            viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
            });

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
       }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
        <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In KO 3.2 no need to do all these workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493265/1090562

Comment: Salvador is correct - it does it automatically in the latest version.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

```html
<body>
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>
        <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
</body>
```

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)

> ### Additional parameters
>
> - valueUpdate
>
>   If your binding also includes a parameter called valueUpdate, this
>     defines which browser event KO should use to detect changes. The
>     following string values are the most commonly useful choices:
>
>   - "change"  (default) - updates your view model when the user
>       moves the focus to a different control,  or in the case of 
>       elements, immediately after any change
>   - "keyup" - updates your view model when the user releases a key
>   - "keypress" - updates your view model when the user has typed a
>       key. Unlike keyup, this updates repeatedly while the user holds a key
>       down
>   - "afterkeydown" - updates your view model as soon as the user
>       begins typing a character. This works by catching the browser’s
>       keydown event and handling the event asynchronously.
>
> Of these options, "afterkeydown" is the best choice if you want to
>   keep your view model updated in real-time.

Comment: awesome, what are the other events, valueUpdate observes?

Comment: from the docs in knockout.js:   // The syntax "after<eventname>" means "run the handler asynchronously after the event"
        // This is useful, for example, to catch "keydown" events after the browser has updated the control

Comment: Is there anyway to get valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' to be the _default_?

Comment: for some input boxes the browser shows "auto-populate" values ( like if the input field is named "firstname" ).  selecting from the auto-populate doesnt work with "afterkeydown".   is there a way to catch this?

Comment: @Anton In addition to auto-populate values, there are also on-screen keyboard clicks and mouse paste events that should be caught.  Using `afterkeydown` is a bad solution.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Good point about the mouse paste events (you can handle those with `afterpaste` I think) but what on-screen keyboards are you talking about? iOS and Android both respond to `keydown`, what devices don't?

Comment: @MattB.  The event is just called "paste," and that should work in most scenarios.  I was just talking about the on-screen keyboard on a regular Windows machine.  However, when I tested the on-screen keyboard in Windows 8 just now, it seemed to register.  My bad!

Comment: I just learned about HTML5's `oninput` event, which covers all the bases. I started an issue for Knockout recommending a feature to allow an `input` value for valueUpdate that would degrade gracefully: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/836

Comment: How to throttle the binding after keydown?

Comment: I have found the `input` event (IE9+) to work very nicely for this purpose, as it will also trigger if you paste something in the text field by right click menu, for instance. http://jsfiddle.net/40fumdem/

Comment: Author of this answer, please update to also include Salvador Dali's answer, textInput added as of 3.2 is a better solution as it has better compatibility with mobile browsers (things like auto complete work better)

Answer (score 87):

In **version 3.2** you can simply use [textinput binding.](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html):

```
<input data-bind="textInput: userName" />
```

It does two important things:

- make immediate updates
- handles browser differences for cut, drag, autocomplete ...

So no need for additional modules, custom controls and other things.

Comment: This works really well and is exactly what I needed to replace the value: field, valueUpdate: 'input change' that I had all through my app... :) thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to capture the event when a user clicks on the 'x' icon on the new HTML5 search input field and act as in the case the input is empty ?

Answer (score 35):

If you want it to do updates on `afterkeydown` "by default," you could inject the `valueUpdate` binding in the `value` binding handler.  Just supply a new `allBindingsAccessor` for the handler to use that includes `afterkeydown`.

```
(function () {
    var valueHandler = ko.bindingHandlers.value;
    var getInjectValueUpdate = function (allBindingsAccessor) {
        var AFTERKEYDOWN = 'afterkeydown';
        return function () {
            var allBindings = ko.utils.extend({}, allBindingsAccessor()),
                valueUpdate = allBindings.valueUpdate;

            if (valueUpdate === undefined) {
                return ko.utils.extend(allBindings, { valueUpdate: AFTERKEYDOWN });
            } else if (typeof valueUpdate === 'string' && valueUpdate !== AFTERKEYDOWN) {
                return ko.utils.extend(allBindings, { valueUpdate: [valueUpdate, AFTERKEYDOWN] });
            } else if (typeof valueUpdate === 'array' && ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(valueUpdate, AFTERKEYDOWN) === -1) {
                valueUpdate = ko.utils.arrayPushAll([AFTERKEYDOWN], valueUpdate);
                return ko.utils.extend(allBindings, {valueUpdate: valueUpdate});
            }
            return allBindings;
        };
    };
    ko.bindingHandlers.value = {
        // only needed for init
        'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            allBindingsAccessor = getInjectValueUpdate(allBindingsAccessor);
            return valueHandler.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
        },
        'update': valueHandler.update
    };
} ());
```

If you're not comfortable "overriding" the `value` binding, you could give the overriding custom binding a different name and use that binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.realtimeValue = { 'init':..., 'update':... };
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LhZB2/1/)

A solution like this would be suitable for Knockout version 2.x.  The Knockout team has fleshed out a more complete binding for text-like inputs through the [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding in Knockout version 3 and up.  It was designed to handle all text input methods for text inputs and `textarea`.  It will even handle real time updating which effectively renders this approach obsolete.

Comment: This way makes my markup a little tidier. Also, in addition to 'afterkeydown', 'input' and 'paste' events can be added to handle paste/drag-and-drop actions.

Comment: In the above solution I think that "typeof valueUpdated === 'array'" needs to be replaced with "Object.prototype.toString.call(valueUpdate) === '[object Array]'".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/javascript-check-if-object-is-array

Answer (score 20):

Jeff Mercado's answer is fantastic, but unfortunately broken with Knockout 3.

But I found the answer suggested by the ko devs while working through Knockout 3 changes. See the bottom comments at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/932. Their code:

```
//automatically add valueUpdate="afterkeydown" on every value binding
(function () {
    var getInjectValueUpdate = function (allBindings) {
        return {
            has: function (bindingKey) {
                return (bindingKey == 'valueUpdate') || allBindings.has(bindingKey);
            },
            get: function (bindingKey) {
                var binding = allBindings.get(bindingKey);
                if (bindingKey == 'valueUpdate') {
                    binding = binding ? [].concat(binding, 'afterkeydown') : 'afterkeydown';
                }
                return binding;
            }
        };
    };

    var valueInitHandler = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return valueInitHandler(element, valueAccessor, getInjectValueUpdate(allBindings), viewModel, bindingContext);
    };
}());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/GKJnt/

**Edit** 
Ko 3.2.0 now has a more complete solution with the new "textInput" binding. See SalvidorDali's answer

Comment: @GrahamT in KO 3.2 you do not even need it. It is [just one line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25493265/1090562)

Comment: Very nice for those of us on KO 3.2 who didn't know about TextInput when we started, and can't update every input in the whole system!