# Ajax POST-request doesn't come through to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm firing an HTTP POST request with Ajax to my php file, but I don't get the desired result. $_POST and $_GET are both empty. I think I'm overlooking something, but I have no clue what.

Here's my code for firing the request:

```
this.save = function() {

    alert(ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]));
    $.ajax("x", {
        data: ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]),
        type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) { alert(result) },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown)}
    });
};
```

Note that I alert the JSON on line 3. That JSON is correct, so the input on line 5 is valid.

My test method in PHP:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array_merge($_POST, $_GET));
exit;
```

The response I'm getting is an empty array.

- I tested the input (see above);
- I know the Ajax call itself succeeds, if I replace that second line in my PHP example with `json_encode(array('success' => true));` I get that back in my page - so the URL is correct.
- I tested it with both GET and POST, with similar negative results.

Comment: can you write the output of ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]) ?

Comment: Can you use the this operator in KnockoutJS? In this line: ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]). There are some docs about this and self.

Comment: `["Name","Description",[{"title":"Page 1","selectedPageStyle":"Header"}]]`

Comment: You should use the console for json, and no need to set the header in PHP.

Comment: dont we have to use dataType : 'json' for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a JSON request, that's why both $_POST and $_GET are empty. Try sending the data like this:

```
$.ajax("x", {
    data: { data: [this.name, this.description, this.pages] },
    type: "post", 
    success: function(result) { alert(result) },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown)}
});
```

Now look inside `$_POST["data"]`.

or if you need to use a JSON request then you need to deserialize it back in your PHP file:

```
$.ajax("x", {
    data: { data: ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]) },
    type: "post", 
    success: function(result) { alert(result) },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown)}
});
```

and then decode:

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and if you want to send pure JSON request in the POST body:

```
$.ajax("x", {
    data: ko.toJSON([this.name, this.description, this.pages]),
    type: "post", 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) { alert(result) },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown)}
});
```

and then:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Notice that `php://input` is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body.

Comment: I wanna send it as JSON. In the examples I'm using (see here http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving) JSON is sent using POST. Why can't I combine JSON and POST? First time I heard that tbh..

Comment: You can combine, look at my second example.

Comment: For some reason I don't get any results at all now. (I obviously changed the url.) The url is correct, but the success alert nor the error alert fires... I'll try to debug.

Comment: Which of the 3 approaches are you using? Try FireBug.

Comment: It's a problem in Opera, it does work in Firefox. Thanks alot! 

I'll figure out what the problem with Opera is. I'm using the third now.

Comment: Little offtopic, but I also opened [a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4386311/1329111) on another Knockout/Javascript issue. I hope you can take the time to take a look.