# Bind two inputs so they display the same text even if one of them was changed by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, knockout.js, bind

The jQuery code looks like this and works fine (probably it look a bit sorter, so please let me know and I'll change it either): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69UAT/)

jQuery:

```
$('.inputs').on('keyup',function(){
    $(this).parent().not(this).find('.inputs').val($(this).val());
}
);
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="hello">
    <input type="text" class="inputs" value="John">
</div>
```

How can I rewrite this code for knockout.js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the below code snippet which will work fine with ko.

```js
var value = "Hello John";
var viewModel = {
  Name: ko.observable(value)
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" class="inputs" id="first">
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:Name" class="inputs" id="second">
</div>
<span data-bind="text: Name"> </span>
```

Hope, You will do this with more data. In that case, Take a look at [this sample](http://jqfaq.com/json-list-to-divs-using-ko/) which will let you know about how to support more data.

For more faqs visit [jqfaq.com](http://jqfaq.com/)

Comment: I don't think your fiddle does exactly what @Haradzieniec has requested. Instead you would need to add `valueUpdate:'keyup'` as an additional `data-bind` binding.

Answer (score 1):

Just bind it to the same observable:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="inputs" id="first" data-bind="value:foobar,valueUpdate:'keyup'">
    <input type="text" class="inputs" id="second" data-bind="value:foobar,valueUpdate:'keyup'">
</div>
```

**ViewModel**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.foobar = ko.observable('hello');
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

I used the `valueUpdate` binding to update the inputs in real time instead of on blur (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391419/664108)