# Is it possible to set valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' as the default valueUpdate in Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Instead of repeating this setting in every text input?

To be clear, I'm talking about this:

```
<input type="text" name="email"data-bind="value: email, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
```

For 90% of my inputs I prefer this above `'change'` - the current default.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: As of last year, the answer appears to have been "you can't, here are some workarounds." Knockout is continually making improvements and has seen a major version number change (v2 to v3) since this discussion began. Is there a way to do this yet?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the default functionality for all text inputs directly. what you can do instead is create a template input and all of those can then just be those templates for example

```
<!-- ko template:{name:'input-template', data: email}--><!--/ko-->
```

By using the containerless notation you avoid creating extra html elements

then just define the template with whatever you want:

```
<script type="text/html" id="input-template">
    <input type="text" name="$data" data-bind="value: $data, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"/>
</script>
```

Comment: Technically this would work, but I would prefer to have something which looks more like common HTML. Thanks for your answer though :)

Comment: May I ask why the traditional html is required other than for aesthetic reasons, as if you're already using knockout, things like the templates and containerless notation can really unlock a lot of the power of knockout, and other developers will already have the learning curve.

Comment: It is indeed about the aesthetics. I might be a bit too much on the nitpicking side of things, but at the moment I prefer adding the boilerplate "valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" above hiding the input element itself. It just conveys more 'meaning' to me. Personal preference I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the existing value bindingHandler to add the afterkeydown binding.

See the brillant solution [How can I get Knockout JS to data-bind on keypress instead of lost-focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386311/how-can-i-get-knockout-js-to-data-bind-on-keypress-instead-of-lost-focus)

Answer (score 0):

If you can "mark" the target inputs with a class, you could try this :

```
$('.yourClass').attr('data-bind', "value: email, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'");
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This is an option, but than there is still boilerplate code involved - the extra class. 
"valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" in that case might not even be that much longer, and show more 'meaning'.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no option in Knockout to change the way the valueUpdate default works, your only option would be to change the Knockout library source to make it work the way you want. This change would have to be made again if the library was ever updated or you can ask the developer of Knockout to add a configuration option where the default valueUpdate event can be changed.