# Call a function on enter key press

Tags: knockout.js

How to call a function using knockout.js when enter key is pressed.. here is my code below.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var inputSelector = 'input,textarea,select';
    $(document).on('keypress', inputSelector, function (e) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        $(element).on('keypress', 'input, textarea, select', function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (keyCode !== 13) {
                alert('a');
                return true;
            }

            var target = e.target;
            target.blur();

            allBindings.enterkey.call(viewModel, viewModel, target, element);
            alert('b');
            return false;
        });
    });
}
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value:sendMessageText, enterkey: sendMessage" />
```

ViewModel

```
function contactsModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.jid=ko.observable();
    self.userName=ko.observable();
    self.sendMsgText=ko.observable();
    self.sendMessage = function(){
        if(self.sendMessageText() == '' )
            alert("Enter something in input field");
        else{
            var message = {
                to : self.userName(),
                message : self.sendMsgText()
            }
            self.sentMessages.push(message);
            sendMessage(message);
        }

     }
 }
```

Any idea's about what is wrong here or suggestions for better approach.

Comment: Can you post the code for your viewModel? Looking at the knockout binding, it is expecting to find a method called sendMessage on viewModel. Your jQuery code to bind to the keypress event may be conflicting with this.

Comment: This question may offer a solution to your issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386311/how-can-i-get-knockout-js-to-data-bind-on-keypress-instead-of-lost-focus

Comment: @DaveRead  i have added viewmodel in question now... pls check.. thanks

Comment: @DaveRead yes i referred to link u provided and similar related links also.. it was of no help in my case becoz it seems there's something i am missing here.. so decided to post a new question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

When you create your own knockout bindingHandler, it is used in the same way as the other bindingHanlders eg: `data-bind="text: myvalue"`

so your HTML will need to look something like this

`<input type="text" data-bind="value:sendMessageText, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterkey: sendMessage"  />`

An important binding to add is the `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` binding. Without this binding when a user types text in the input and hits enter the onblur event is not raised prior to `enterkey` binding. This results in the observable returning an unexpected value and not the current text if the input's value is accessed in an action invoked by `enterKey`.

[Another Look at Custom Bindings for KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html)

**EDIT**
This is what I have used previously on other projects.
[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/crSns/71/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterkey = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        var callback = valueAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                callback.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: you are correct.. I tried this.. But didn't worked. Using jquery keypress event for now.. If any other better solution you have using knockout I .. Welcome

Comment: Updated question with respect to your answer.problem still persist

Comment: how so? did you check out the jsFiddle Demo?

Comment: Added information for `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` to ensure expected behavior

Comment: The problem is, in this answer, the binding is named `enterkey` but inside the init it's looking for `executeOnEnter`.  line 7 should be `allBindings.enterkey.call()` instead of `allBindings.executeOnEnter.call()`

Comment: Thanks @HDog.  Code was originally executeOnEnter for the binding name. I have updated it to be consistent.

Comment: i had to add `valueUpdate` handler as   `data-bind="value: organisationName, valueUpdate: 'input',  executeOnEnter:initialize" `

Comment: Add `element.blur();` just before `allBindings.enterkey.call(viewModel);` call and that way your not backed into the corner of having to specify a `valueUpdate`. Adding `valueUpdate` makes a lots of applications overly chatty if its talking to the back-end via ajax.

Answer (score 103):

No need for a custom binding, just use knockout's keypress event([Knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)):

```
<input type="text"
       data-bind="textInput : keyword, 
                  event: {keypress: onEnter}" >
</input>
```

And your function:

```
that.onEnter = function(d,e){
    e.keyCode === 13 && that.search();  
    return true;
};
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2nvszsfj/)

EDIT: New binding from knockout(3.2.0) : textInput - obviates the need to have a valueUpdate binding.

Comment: Maybe the return statement is unnecessary: it's not used in the docs examples.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me, thanks to @DaafVader for most of it.

in view

```
<input data-bind="value: searchText, valueUpdate: 'input', event: { keyup: searchKeyUp }" />
```

in viewmodel

```
var searchKeyUp = function (d, e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        search();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the submit binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html) on the form around your input, that's what it's made for.

Example from the Knockout docs:

```
<form data-bind="submit: doSomething">
    ... form contents like inputs go here ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        doSomething : function(formElement) {
            // ... now do something
        }
    };
</script>
```

It also automatically handles your button if there is one.

Answer (score 3):

And this worked for me, thanks to @DaafVader.

in view:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" 
      data-bind="value : keyword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
</input>
```

in javascript:

```
$("#myInput").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            search();
        }
});
```

To put keyup event in your jquery event instead of knockout event reduced the complexity of the knockout viewmodel.