# Why is knockout.js textInput binding not working?

Tags: knockout.js

Example taken from the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) and stuck to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kolkabes/Lvuvh2pc/) doesn't work.
Code snippet for completeness:

```
<p>Login name: <input data-bind="textInput: userName" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" data-bind="textInput: userPassword" /></p>

ViewModel:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>

<script>
    ko.applyBindings({
        userName: ko.observable(""),        // Initially blank
        userPassword: ko.observable("abc")  // Prepopulate
    });
</script>
```

I've tried it in an incognito window thinking that some browser extension might be messing with it. No luck.

Expected behavior is that *viewModels*'s JSON dump should be updated with each keystroke in any of the input fields change.

If I switch to *value* binding instead of *textInput* it does update whenever input focus changes.

Has anyone encountered this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `textInput` binding was added in a later version of Knockout.JS ([3.2.0](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/08/18/knockout-3-2-0-released/)).
 Add the updated library to your fiddle and it works.

Comment: You're right! It came from here https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1160 I should have checked for that. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same problem and unfortunately, jsfiddle did not list anything newer as KO 3.0. Added 3.2 manually as external source and worked like a charm! The KO docs should really mention the minimum version though, like jQuery does.

Comment: Agreed @CoDEmanX, it seems like they prefer people on latest currently which sometimes is just not possible.

Comment: Same here. New projects created as "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" contain Knockout 2.2.0 - and textInput binding doesn´t work.

Comment: @huha The builtin projects for Visual Studio tend to have older references.  You're well off to remove them and get latest from Nuget Package Manager whenever starting a new project from a template!

Comment: For reference - I was using Durandal v2.1.0 and it came with Knockout 3.1.0. Which is why I'm here...

Answer (score 8):

If you are stuck on an older version of Knockout you can use valueUpdate

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" />
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4391419/1058292